# When click on menu, it opens, when click again it close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have very basic:

```
        // jQuery Document
  var main = function() {
  /* Push the body and the nav over by 285px over */
  $('#share').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      right: "0px"
    }, 200);

    $('body').animate({
      right: "285px"
    }, 200);
  });

  /* Then push them back */
  $('html').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      right: "-285px"
    }, 200);

    $('body').animate({
      right: "0px"
    }, 200);
  });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

And, I want to do something like this.. If user clicks on menu icon (#share), menu will appear, if menu is visible and user clicks again, it will disappear..How to SIMPLY do it?? i want to do it just as simple as possible... please help me :)

And yeah... I wrote something like if html. click.. then close the menu.. There should be the name of the menu icon (#share)

there is menus css:

```
.menu {
  background-color: #373737;
  right: -285px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
}
```

and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Minecraft</title>
        <link href="styles_m.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head


    <body>
    <div class="menu">

    </div>

        <div id="header">
        <div id="main">
            <a href="minecraft.html"><img src="my_logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="share">
            <img name="menu" src="my_menu.png">
        </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">

        </script>
    </body
</html>
```

Comment: Add HTML too or create a jsfiddle demo

Comment: @PetrCihlar Check out my answer boss... Doesn't use much variables...

Comment: Yeah, its very good, but I used another.. but thanks a lot bro :) I will give you a point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `fadeToggle()`:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".showMenu").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".menu").fadeToggle(400);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="showMenu">Show Menu</button>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or if you wanna make it slide right, you can use animations:

Just use `animate()`:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".showMenu").click(function () {
    if ($(this).next(".menu").css("left") != "0px")
      $(this).next(".menu").animate({
        left: 0
      }, 1000);
    else
      $(this).next(".menu").animate({
        left: -250
      }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="showMenu">Show Menu</button>
<div class="menu" style="position: relative; left: -250px;">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a variable control to know when to show/hide the element ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/o4xbr3dy/)):

```
var control = false;
var main = function() {
    $('#share').click(function() {
        if( control === true ){
            $('.menu').animate({
                right: "-285px"
            }, 200);

            $('body').animate({
                right: "0px"
            }, 200);
            control = false;
            return;
        }
        control = true;
        $('.menu').animate({ right: "0px" }, 200);
        $('body').animate({ right: "285px" }, 200);
    });
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I thing You have the best answer... Its easy and well made... thanks a lot... :)

Comment: However, 
 when i click on icon, it wil slowly fade in, when i click it again, it wil... just move it right... without my 400 speed...why??

Comment: I am glad if I have helped :)

Comment: I am not sure what happens to your current code, anyway, to make animations, the elements must have already declared the property to animate. I mean, if you need to animate the width of an element, that element must have already declared its width. If you see you will get in trouble again, just post a new question for the new problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('button').click(function() {

  $('.menu').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<div class="menu" style="display:none;">
  <ul>
    <li>menu 1</li>
    <li>menu1</li>
    <li>menu 3</li>
    <li>menu 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 data tags can be the solutions. Have a look at my fiddle

```js
$('.showMenu').click(function() {
  var active = $('.menu').data('active');
  
  if(active === 'N') {
    $('.showMenu').html('Hide Menu');
    $('.menu').fadeIn(100);
    $('.menu').data('active', 'Y');
  } else {
    $('.showMenu').html('Show Menu');
    $('.menu').fadeOut(100);
    $('.menu').data('active', 'N');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="showMenu">Show Menu</button>
<div class="menu" data-active="N" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `fadeToggle` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('icon').click(function() {
        $('dropdown element').fadeToggle(400);
    });
});
```

An example can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadetoggle.asp